# Existence of certain idempotents

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $T$ is an idempotent (that is $T^2=T$)  of infinite rank and co-rank on a separable Hilbert space. Can we find an idempotent $S$ such that $\overline{TS(H)}=(Id-S)(H)$?

Comment: @Crostul: Pretty sure it means the image under the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can even get $\operatorname{ran}(TS) = \ker S $, without taking the closure on the left.

Let $A:\ker T\to H$ be any isomorphism; composing it with a projection $H\to \ker T$ we get a linear operator $B:H\to H$ such that $B(\ker T) = H $. Define
$$S = T^\perp + TBT^\perp,\quad \text{ where } T^\perp = I-T$$
I leave it for you to check that

1. $S^2=S$
2. $\operatorname{ran}(I-S) = \ker S = \operatorname{ran} T$
3. $\operatorname{ran} (TS) = \operatorname{ran}T$.

---

The idea of construction is that for a given idempotent $Q$, the formula 
$$Q+Q^\perp B Q,\quad B:H\to H$$
describes all idempotents with the same kernel as $Q$. Similarly, the formula
$$Q+Q B Q^\perp,\quad B:H\to H$$
describes all idempotents with the same range as $Q$.